# Verify that a given string can be converted into a positive integer

Tags: java, integer

I wrote method that checks if a given String input can be parsed as positive integer or not.

Is there a cleaner way to write this so I'm not repeating the code that rejects the value?

```
try {
  int num = Integer.parseInt(value);

  if (num <= 0) {
    errors.rejectValue(FIELD_FILE, INVALID_MESSAGE_KEY, new Object[]{lineNumber, fieldName}, "Line {0}: {1} must be a positive integer");
  }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    errors.rejectValue(FIELD_FILE, INVALID_MESSAGE_KEY, new Object[]{lineNumber, fieldName}, "Line {0}: {1} must be a positive integer");
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should be repeating your rejection message, since you have two different rejection scenarios. Or you could simply throw a new NumberFormatException if num <= 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this is the cleaner you can get.
Even if it passes on the try if it is not in the range of results that you expect you force it into the catch.

```
try {
  int num = Integer.parseInt(value);

  if (num <= 0) {
    throw new NumberFormatException();
  }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    errors.rejectValue(FIELD_FILE, INVALID_MESSAGE_KEY, new Object[]{lineNumber, fieldName}, "Line {0}: {1} must be a positive integer");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way:

```
int num = 0;
try {
   num = Integer.parseInt(value);
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    num = -1;
 }
 if (num <= 0) {
   errors.rejectValue(FIELD_FILE, INVALID_MESSAGE_KEY, new Object[]{lineNumber, fieldName}, "Line {0}: {1} must be a positive integer");
 }
```